# Extract list of Twitter follower IDs using Tweepy API v2: Exception 400

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am simply trying to extract the followers of a Twitter profile using the following code. However, for some unknown reason, the `id` query parameter value is not valid. I have tried to input the user id of several Twitter accounts to see if the problem lied with the `id` rather than my code. The problem is in the code...

```
def create_url_followers(max_results):
    # params based on the get_users_followers endpoint
    query_params_followers = {'max_results': max_results,  # The maximum number of results to be returned per page
                              'pagination_token': {}}  # Used to request the next page of results
    return query_params_followers


def connect_to_endpoint_followers(url, headers, params):
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=params)
    print("Endpoint Response Code: " + str(response.status_code))
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(response.status_code, response.text)
    return response.json()


# Inputs for the request
bearer_token = auth() # retrieves the token from the environment
headers = create_headers(bearer_token)
max_results = 100 # number results i.e. followers of pol_id
```

To run the code in a for loop I add the `id` in the position for `id` in the URL and loop through the list of ids while appending results to the `json_response_followers`.

```
pol_ids_list = house["Uid"].astype(str).values.tolist() # create list of politician ids column Uid in df house.

json_response_followers = [] # empty list to append Twitter data
for id in pol_ids_list: # loop over ids in list pol_ids_list
    url = (("https://api.twitter.com/2/users/" + id + "/followers"), create_url_followers(max_results))
    print(url)
    json_response_followers.append(connect_to_endpoint_followers(url[0], headers, url[1])) # append data to list json_response_list

    sleep(60.5)  # sleep for 60.5 seconds since API limit is 
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here could be that you're specifying `pol_id` as a parameter, which would be appended to the call. In the case of this API, you want to *insert* the value of `pol_id` at the point where `:id` is in the URL. The `max_results` and `pagination_token` values should be appended.

Try checking the value of `url` before calling `connect_to_endpoint_followers`.

I think you are currently trying to call

`https://api.twitter.com/2/users/:id/followers?id=2891210047&max_results=100&pagination_token=`

This is not valid, as there's no value for `:id` in the URI where it belongs, and the `id` parameter itself is not valid / is essentially a duplicate of what should be `:id`.

It should be:

`https://api.twitter.com/2/users/2891210047/followers?max_results=100&pagination_token=`

Comment: Hi @Andy, thank you for taking the time. The url in the second to last line is `('https://api.twitter.com/2/users/:id/followers', {'id': '2891210047', 'max_results': 100, 'pagination_token': {}})`.

Comment: You will need to construct a URL with parameters arranged as I’ve described.

Comment: Indeed the code works if I define `url = ('https://api.twitter.com/2/users/2891210047/followers', {'max_results': 100, 'pagination_token': {}})`. However, I am not sure which lines I should change in the code to insert the value of `pol_id` at the point where `:id` is in the URL. 1. step would be to remove `'id': pol_id` from `query_params_followers`. I could insert the `pol_id` manually in the second line as so `search_url_followers = "https://api.twitter.com/2/users/2891210047/followers"` though that will not work when I later use a for loop to extract followers from a list of pol_ids.

Comment: I came up with a solution that can be used in a for loop (see code above). Though it is probably not the most efficient nor the prettiest... Without your help, I would not have realized the initial issue so thank you @Andy